# How to simplify SQL code for "MAX" operator

Tags: sql, sql-max

I was trying to solve one task and found the solution, it works, but the code is "awful" and duplicates itself, may be someone can just help me with that?

```
SELECT  b."N",b."ID",max(b.summ) as "jjj", b.country

FROM(SELECT großhandelsfirma.name as "N",großhandelsfirma.steuerid as "ID",
sum(verkauft.anzahl) as "summ", großhandelsfirma.land as "country"
FROM großhandelsfirma
INNER JOIN verkauft on großhandelsfirma.name = verkauft.ghname
GROUP BY großhandelsfirma.name,großhandelsfirma.steuerid,großhandelsfirma.land) b
WHERE b.summ in (SELECT  max(b.summ)

FROM(SELECT großhandelsfirma.name as "N",großhandelsfirma.steuerid as "ID",
sum(verkauft.anzahl) as "summ", großhandelsfirma.land as "country"
FROM großhandelsfirma
INNER JOIN verkauft on großhandelsfirma.name = verkauft.ghname
GROUP BY großhandelsfirma.name,großhandelsfirma.steuerid,großhandelsfirma.land) b
GROUP BY b.country)
GROUP BY b."N",b."ID", b.country
```

Original code was ok, but gave me solution with not needed lines, the main task was to find company with highest "sum" in each country, but I got some duplicates with countries, so answer included 2-3 best "summs" in 1 country, but I needed only 1.

This was the old code:

```
SELECT großhandelsfirma.name as N, großhandelsfirma.steuerid as ID,
sum verkauft.anzahl as summ, großhandelsfirm.land as country
FROM großhandelsfirma
INNER JOIN verkauft on großhandelsfirma.name = verkauft.ghname
GROUP BY großhandelsfirma.name, großhandelsfirma.steuerid, großhandelsfirma.land
```

Comment: [mcve] is a great start when askign SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the window function ROW_NUMBER has been implemented in your RDBMS.
It can be used to calculate a number based on an order.
So it'll be 1 for the top 1.

```
SELECT N, ID, country, summ
FROM
(
  SELECT f.name as N, f.steuerid as ID, f.land as country
  , SUM(v.anzahl) as summ
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.land ORDER BY SUM(v.anzahl) DESC) as RN
  FROM großhandelsfirma f
  JOIN verkauft v ON f.name = v.ghname
  GROUP BY f.name, f.steuerid, f.land
) q
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try doing the same with CTE?  Please have a look into below link.

[CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Or else use the TOP 1 from the result filtered.